# How to render a view into another one, after an ajax request in C# and ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, .net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm new at programming using ASP.NET MVC with C#. My problem is the next, I have a form to do an advanced search, that send every field in an ajax request. In the controller I receive all information and then I save it into a SQL table. I can Access this search in another view by accessing the corresponding URL, for example `searches/viewSearch/123`. What I need is to render the view just after I saved the search in my table, in the same view where I have my form.

Comment: What have you tried? Could you post any relevant code as well to reproduce the issue?

Comment: RedirectToAction("viewSearch",123(id)).. you might need to do something like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommendation is to use `Partial Views`.  Move your table to a partial view, your view can then load that partial view via Ajax when you want to access the corresponding url. You can also use

```
@{
    Html.RenderPartial("_yourpartialview");
}
```

instead of an ajax call.

Comment: Thanx for the answer, I'm now reading about partial views and it seems to be what I need.